# Best Practice/Design-Pattern for using general Methods

Tags: java, android, c++, design-patterns

Say I have a method that is used for opening application with an android app from a sidebar

```
openApplication(Sidebar s, Context c ... )
```

and now I want to use this openApplication to open from a Topbar

```
openApplication(TopBar t, Context c ... )
```

The function `openApplication` is very similiar but needs to do little-changes based on Sidebar or TopBar attributes/ members

I dont what to make two different functions that basically do the same thing but different in 2-3 lines of code. What is good practice for approaches like this

I was considering passing a boolean or enum to the function to tell the difference but then I would have lots of `if statements` in the function for little things. Was also condering making private members `_topbar, _sidebar` but then if statements again ?

Is there a good practice to generalize functions ? or design pattern out there?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: Have you considered using an `enum`? For example: `typedef enum{ SIDEBAR, TOPBAR } BarLocation;` and then declaring the function as `openApplication(BarLocation loc, Context c ... );` Your code would then just need to do a small if-else selection statement to decide `if(loc == SIDEBAR){ ... }else{ ... }`.

Comment: @sjdowling, perhaps the OP is using [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: @SpencerDoak what if i need to access certain functions for topbar and sidebar ? should i store those at private variables ?

Comment: Functions != Variables, so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @SpencerDoak if I take in BarLocation loc, I wont be able to do something like Sidebar s.getLengthofSidebar() ... since i need to pass in s for this in the function

Comment: Well, if you're using C++ like your tags state, you could also pass a void pointer and convert it to the relevant type, but that's way more work. At that point, just use 2 different functions rather than trying to combine them.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the common interface or superclass that both Topbar and Sidebar share, and use that as the type.